# How to select tuples in SQL with the largest specific attibutes

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, tuples

I'm trying to figure out how to list tuples in SQL with the largest specific attributes. For example, say I have table:

```
Cars(make, model, year, engineSize, pistonCapacity)
```

and I want to list the tuple(s) with the largest piston capacity.

For example, lets say we have:

> ```
> Lexus,  SC430  ,  1997,  6,  3.8
> Ford ,  Mustang,  1986,  8,  5.0
> GMC  ,  Denali ,  2009,  8,  6.5
> Ford ,  F350   ,  2009,  8,  6.5
> ```

I would want to list the GMC Denali and the Ford F350. I tried this query:

```
SELECT make, model
FROM Cars
ORDER BY pistonCapacity DESC limit 1
```

which lists only the GMC Denali.

I then tried this query:

```
SELECT make, model
FROM Cars
HAVING MAX(pistonCapacity)
```

but no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @todda.speot.is: not necessarily. Postgresql also has it for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT make, model
FROM Cars
WHERE pistonCapacity=(SELECT MAX(pistonCapacity) FROM Cars)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your RDBMS, but in Oracle (and probably most others) you can do

```
SELECT make, model
FROM Cars
WHERE pistonCapacity = (SELECT max(pistonCapacity) FROM Cars)
```

Comment: @todda.speot.is: not necessarily. Postgresql also has it for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      c.make, c.model
FROM 
      Cars AS c
  JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX(pistonCapacity) AS maxPistonCapacity
        FROM Cars
      ) AS cm
    ON
        cm.maxPistonCapacity = m.pistonCapacity
```